# Using strong types with $ in Polymer Dart not working

Tags: types, casting, dart, dart-polymer

This is a problem that keeps cropping up for me with Polymer and Dart.

When using an element from the polymer_elements project, I find I can't access properties or methods on those elements without eliciting warnings in the Dart Editor. The code runs, but the warnings get annoying once there are lots of them.

```
$["header-collapse"].toggle();   // creates a warning (Element does not have method "toggle")
```

In the above line, the element with an ID of "header-collapse" is a PolymerCollapse element from the polymer_elements package. But if I import the appropriate Dart file and try to typecast it as such, I get exceptions. So this does not work:

```
PolymerCollapse headerCollapse = $["header-collapse"];   // does not work!
```

Setting breakpoints and examining what $["header-collapse"] returns has not been helpful so far. Anyone know how I could get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the contributors of the polymer_elements/polymer_ui_elements.

This is very annoying but we have no solution for this either. There is an open bug (I will add the link tomorrow - I'm on the phone now)

The best you can do is to not to import the elements in Dart, only in HTML and ignore the warnings otherwise pub build won't work.